# Setup gitlab-ci services through config files

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I went through the gitlab-ci documentation a couple of times and I cannot find whether it is possible to setup the docker services through a config file. The [services example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/) in the documentation, shows only basic examples with `mysql`,`redis` and `postgresql`.

If I have a service like `nginx`, can I pass the configuration file (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), to override the one from the service or is the setup only through variables?

Answer (score 0):

It will be delivered soon in GitLab 16.9 (until ~ Feb 9, 2024).
Please see the issue description and current workaround: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/28121#note_1675743672

One more workaround: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3210